# command is working on terminal but not in the script

Tags: raspbian, linux, mount, script, terminal

I am using raspbian in headless mode and I am trying to mount USB on USB insertion. Script is executing but USB mount command failing.

here is the script, filename is **automount.sh** (this script gets executed on USB insertion)

Code: Select all

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mount /dev/sd*1 /media/backup
date >> /home/pi/log.log
```

I can see that log.log file is created but "**sudo mount /dev/sd*1 /media/backup**" is not working.
if I copy the same command and paste it into the terminal then it works.

I don't understand what is the exact issue.

If I execute the script using sudo

`sudo ./automount.sh`

then scripts works properly.

Comment: Including the actual error message would be useful.

Comment: i don't see any error message. but I have updated more info in main post.

Comment: i have same question on rpi community as well. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=320758&p=1920310#p1920310

Comment: @dev_eng looks like a linux related question ... not RPi specific ... you are asking in the wrong places

Comment: yeah but i am using raspberry pi and it is related to raspberry pi as well.

Comment: try logging the username to get additional info

Comment: @dev_eng if you were running Linux on a Dell laptop, would you ask at a Dell site?

Comment: it is likely not running as root if it needs sudo.  you can make the owner of the script root, make it run as root via the permissions bits.  be sure to lock down write permissions to the script, else someone can replace it and run arbitrary code as root.  https://superuser.com/questions/922172/linux-is-it-possible-to-run-script-as-file-owner/922183

Comment: Sorry we got cut off when the site went offline for a while: *"i don't see any error message"* -> You would if you changed `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` and put `exec &>> /home/pi/log.log` at the top (then you can remove the redirect on `date`).  Change the location of the log to somewhere world writable (`/tmp`) and don't create it.  This way the log gets written no matter who the user is (you can get that by adding `id` somewhere).  You should also go into better detail about how the *"script gets executed on USB insertion"*.

Comment: **WHY** would anyone WANT to use a script to "auto mount" a drive? Use /etc/fstab which is designed for the purpose.

Comment: because i will be using number of USB drives and I think for fstab requires UUID to mention to mount. that's why I went through udev approach for mounting.